# CSS3 column-count

Tags: image, css, responsive-design

I have a div which has a width of 100%, inside this I have about 10 images, all of which are different widths and sizes. I want to be able to seamlessly float these images around each other, I have managed this but they don't stretch across the screen, they're all resized to the same column width...is there anyway I can change this so they stay they're respective size but fill in around each other?

I have this:

```
.images {
   line-height:0;
   -webkit-column-count:6;
   -webkit-column-gap:0px;
   -moz-column-count:6;
   -moz-column-gap:0px;
   column-count:6;
   column-gap:0px;
   background:#545454;
   width:100%;
   display:inline-block;
}

.images img {
  width:100% !important;
  height:auto !important;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `column` properties are for setting text in columns so that text flow continues from the end of a column to the start of the next column. It’s not a good idea to use them for images.

Depending on what you mean by the implied goals “seamlessly float these images around each other” and “stretch across the screen” and “they stay they're respective size but fill in around each other”, you might something as simple as just putting `img` elements one after another *or* using `float: left` *or* putting them in an HTML table or simulating that with CSS `table` properties.

Comment: Thanks, I think the main thing I'm after is a masonry effect http://masonry.desandro.com/ where gaps are filled between the images which I can't really do with a float. I will look in to it thanks.